# How to get the name of the windows default user group

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, user-management, access-control-list, user-permissions

We want to change file permissions for the windows default user group.

The problem is, depending on windows version (xp,win 7) and language, the name of this default user group differs. Sometimes the name of the group is "Benutzer", sometimes it is "User".

How can I get this name programmatically?

Comment: WTF is a 'default user group'?

Comment: The user group which name is "Users" in english, that is normal users for the computer which have not admin rights. the group exists of every windows pc after installation.

Comment: There's no difference in the name between versions, only languages. The name is Users regardless of whether it's W2K, WinXP, W2K3, Vista, W2K8, or Win7.

Comment: No, in german Windows XP the name is "VORDEFINIERT/Benutzer"

Comment: What I meant is that for each version there is a USERS group. There is no other name for the group. The name may translate differently in other languages but it still translates to USERS, as opposed to the name being something different, like BOB.

Comment: Sure, but to change permission for that group, I need to specify the actual name for that group in my script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be changing the name of the group. Rather, you should be referencing the group by its [well-known SID](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330). You can't guarantee what the names of built-in groups will be in other localized versions of Windows, or in future versions, but the well-known SIDs will stay the same.

Comment: Which of them is the default users group?

Comment: The default user group (when creating local users) is Users. The default user group (when creating domain users) is Domain Users. In addition, when joining a computer to a domain, the Domain Users group is added as a member of the local Users group and the Domain Admins group is added as a member of the local Administrators group.

Comment: Which SID will this be?

Comment: @codymanix: S-1-5-32-545 is the SID you're looking for.

Comment: So true. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330

Comment: Ah thanks a google search for this number brough light into me :)